# How do I make a white histogram with black outline?

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

```
array = np.random.normal(0, 1, 10000)
plt.hist(array, bins = 9, color = "w")
plt.xlabel("Bins")
plt.ylabel("Frequency")
```

This gives me an empty histogram, or rather it looks empty because the background and the histogram are the same color. How do I add a black outline?

I tried adding

```
edgecolor = 'black'
```

This does not produce the desired result. I only want the outline to be on the outside of the histogram, I believe the perimeter only.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to complete it doing this:

```
histtype='step'
```